# Reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++

**This is Leetcode 2215 i dont know why I am getting this error I encountered it for the very first time can anyone tell me why it is occurring here and way to solve it.**

code :

```
vector<vector<int>> findDifference(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
    int n = nums1.size();
    int m = nums2.size();
    
    set<int> ans1;
    set<int> ans2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        {
        ans1.insert(nums1[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)    {
        ans2.insert(nums2[i]);
        ans1.erase(nums2[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    {
        ans2.erase(nums1[i]);
    }
    vector<vector<int>> ans;
    for (auto itr = ans1.begin(); itr != ans1.end(); itr++) {
    ans[0].push_back(*itr);
}
    for (auto itr = ans2.begin(); itr != ans2.end(); itr++) {
    ans[1].push_back(*itr);
}
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
vector<vector<int>> ans;
ans[0].push_back(*itr);
```

`ans[0]` does not exist.  You can fix it like this:

```
vector<vector<int>> ans(2);
```

That creates two `vector<int>` instances right away, so you can access them as `ans[0]` and `ans[1]`.